# How to save form data from base.html in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

In my app, I have created a `context_proccessors.py` to show the form to `base.html` file.

I am able to show the form in the `base.html` file. But the problem I am facing is I have no idea how to save that form data from `base.html` since there is no `view` for the `base.html`. Below is my code:

`models.py`

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_posts')
    post_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pic', verbose_name="Image")
    post_caption = models.TextField(max_length=264, verbose_name="Caption")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}"
```

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from post_app.models import Posts


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        exclude = ('user',)
```

`context_proccessors.py`

```
from post_app.forms import PostForm


def post_form(request):
    form = PostForm
    return {
        'post_form': form,
    }
```

`base.html`

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ post_form|crispy }}
                    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>

</form>
```

I want the form to be displayed on every page so that the user can submit data from anywhere

Comment: Why isn't there a view? you need to make one to handle the post request you'd be sending to it

Comment: Yes, But I don't know how to do that, I am new to django. And all the tutorials I have found are about creating view for {page}.html not for base.html. That is why I couldn't get an Idea for this.

Comment: This is exactly the same, you have a url that you post your form to, theres no difference in how it'd work between this and a full page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the answer by `N T` I have implemented this. So, I had to make a URL pattern for the view and use that URL pattern in the action in the form of `base.html`.

`view.py`

```
@login_required
def postsaveview(request):
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            user_obj.user = request.user
            user_obj.slug = str(request.user) + str(uuid.uuid4())
            user_obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile_app:profile'))
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post-save/', views.postsaveview, name='post-save'),
]
```

`base.html`

```
<form action="{% url "post-save" %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ post_form|crispy }}
                    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def PostView(request):
  form = PostForm()
  if request.method == 'GET':
     return render(request, 'base.html', {form:form})
  elif request.method == 'POST':
     form.save(request.data)
```

In the views.py of your app you can define this view, and the you have to provide it an url in the urls.py of the root directory. So evere time there is a request on that url, if the method is GET, the form will be rendered on base.html file, if the method is POST, the post will be saved.